Are Prof. Arora and Barak maintaining Computation Complexity: A Modern Approach?
Does the book Computation Complexity: A Modern Approach have an official errata page like Knuth's books and CLRS, maintaining by their authors? I have tried to find its comprehensive errata page to revise my copy but gotten partial errata pages. Moreover, they don't seem to be updated recently.
I have also sent a reporting email to complexitybook@gmail.com, which found on here, but they haven't replied yet.
